# I try scrape barchart.com with "html" and urllib3.PoolManager()

Tags: python, xpath, request, urllib3

this script retrieves the site data well but I don't know how to read the value ('lastPrice') "> 30.67 <here someone can help me thank you

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding:Utf8 -*-
from lxml import html
import urllib3.request
url = "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/$VIX"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', url, headers={'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.16 Safari/537.36','Cookie':'cookie_name=cookie_value'})        
page = r.data
data_string = page.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
tree = html.fromstring(data_string)
x_pat= "/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]"
valtab = tree.xpath(x_pat)
valtab= valtab[0].text
print(valtab.strip())
#[[ item.lastPrice ]]
# I also try!!!!!
valtab = tree.xpath(x_pat)
print(valtab)
#[<Element span at 0x38700e0>]
for line in valtab:
    l=line.items()
    print(l)
    #[('class', 'last-change'), ('data-ng-class', "highlightValue('lastPrice')")]
    l=line.text_content()
    print(l)
    #[[ item.lastPrice ]]
```

Comment: welcome to SO! Can you post what output you are getting and what output you would like to have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.